# What is a Light Efficient System?

Tags: visible-light, microscopy, imaging

When reading [this](http://labs.pbrc.edu/cellbiology/documents/BioTechniquesGuidetoDeconvolution.pdf) paper, I encountered this sentence on the sixth page:

> When used in conjunction with
>   wide-field microscopy, iterative restoration
>   methods are light efficient. This is
>   most valuable in light-limited applications
>   such as high-resolution fluorescence
>   imaging, where objects are
>   typically small and contain few fluorophores
>   (15,18), or in live-cell fluorescence
>   imaging, where exposure times
>   are limited by the extreme sensitivity of
>   live cells to phototoxicity (9,24,46,54).

What exactly does it mean by **light efficient** here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the techniques reduces the amount of light the organism under the microscope is exposed to - it is efficient in its use of light. I haven't read the paper in depth to understand why this might be so.

Comment: Does this not mean that the amount of light being transmitted by the illumination system is the amount of light being picked up by the microscope? At least I would have thought that's what ties in with 'efficiency'.

Comment: Two things -- In this context of the following sentences, I think that it's the light the organism is being exposed to (not 'transmitted by the illumination system'), and I think it's maximising the efficiency, bu not necessarily increasing it to 100%. 

If you were to try to analyse it numerically, it might be efficiency = (light interacting with specimen that is collected) / (light interacting with specimen).

Comment: Yeah that makes quite a bit of sense really, thank you!